# Can $x\mapsto x+\dfrac{2^{\nu_2(x)}}{3}$ be made differentiable at $0$ in $\Bbb Q_2$?

Tags: calculus, p-adic-number-theory

I'm interested in whether I can make $x\mapsto x+\dfrac{2^{\nu_2(x)}}{3}$ differentiable at $0$ in $\Bbb Q_2$.

For the avoidance of doubt I'm defining $2^{\nu_2(0)}=0$

---

My attempt is:

$\displaystyle f'(x)=\lim_{x\to a}\dfrac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$

Then as a first example I'm taking $x=0$ and looking at the sequence $a=2^n:n\to\infty$

$\displaystyle f'(x)=\lim_{n\to \infty}\dfrac{2^n+2^n/3}{2^n}=4/3$

Of course there are two routes to take here:

$2^n/2^n=1$, or

$2^n/2^n=1$ provided $2^n\neq0$, because at $2^n=0$ we have a division by zero.

Is there a serious problem with the $2^n/2^n=1$ answer?

---

Here's a concern I have with the $2^n/2^n=1$ **provided $n\neq0$** answer: I am pretty certain the function topologically conjugates to another function $f$, which exchanges the point at zero with another point in the space, whose derivative is well-defined.  That seems problematic to me.

Comment: $2^n/2^n=1$, even when $n=0$. After all, $2^0=1$.

Comment: @Mastrem i had a slight typo when you looked - it is not $n=0$, it is $2^n=0$.  my apologies.  your comment may not apply.

Comment: The difference quotient is $1+\frac{2^{v_2(x)}}{3x}$ which is well-defined for all $x\ne0$. But if you take $x=a2^n$ with $a\equiv 1~(2)$ and take $n\to\infty$ you get a limit that depends on $a$... so the original limit doesn't exist.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: $2^{\nu_2(x)} = \frac{1}{\lvert x \rvert_2}$, right? Which at least has the suggested removable discontinuity at $0$ when viewed as a function $\mathbb Q_2 \rightarrow \mathbb Q_2$. (While if considered as function $\mathbb Q_2 \rightarrow \mathbb R$ has a non-removable discontinuity at $0$. Whereas for the absolute value $\lvert x\rvert_2$, it's the other way around, continuous as function to reals but with a nonremovable discontinuity when its values are viewed as $2$-adic numbers.)

Comment: Thanks @Torsten. A brain fart.

Comment: But, still we have for $a=0$, $x_n=2^n$
$$\frac{f(x_n)-f(0)}{x_n-0}=\frac{2^n(1+\frac13)}{2^n}\to4/3$$
but with $x_n=-2^n$ we get
$$\frac{f(x_n)-f(0)}{x_n-0}=\frac{2^n(-1+\frac13)}{-2^n}\to2/3?$$
Or have I lost it :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen i agree I get the same as you.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen is the problem restricted to positive vs negative numbers and can contiuity be achieved as simply as multiplying the function over the negative numbers by two, or is it more complex than that? I suspect the latter but can you confirm? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4832232/is-f-differentiable-over-all-bbb-z-2

Comment: thanks @coiso i agree and Jyrki's comment exhibits an example. Make it an answer if you like. do you have a view on my last comment? ^^

Comment: There is no natural *positive-negative* dichotomy in $\Bbb{Q}_2$. And none can exist if we insist (as we usually do) that the set of positive elements should be closed under sums and products.

Comment: Sorry @JyrkiLahtonen in the linked question I restricted to periodic 2-adics for that reason but failed to do so in that last comment.

Answer (score 0):

To sum up comments and get this off the unanswered list:

First of all, for the purposes of this question, the behaviour of the function $g(x) = x + \dfrac{2^{\nu_2(x)}}{3}$ at $0$ is easily translated to that of $f(x) = 3\cdot g(x) - 3x = 2^{\nu_2(x)} = \frac{1}{\lvert x \rvert_2}$ at $0$.

This $f$, when viewed as a (locally constant!) function $(\mathbb Q_2\setminus \{0\}, \lvert\cdot\rvert_2) \rightarrow (\mathbb Q_2, \lvert\cdot\rvert_2)$, can be made continuous at $0$ by setting $f(0)=0$. But this extension is not differentiable at $0$:

In fact, any sequence $(x_n)_n$ in $\mathbb Q_2\setminus \{0\}$ which $2$-adically goes to $0$ can be written $x_n = u_n 2^{y_n}$, with $(y_n)_n$ a sequence of natural numbers going to infinity, and $(u_n)_n$ a sequence of $2$-adic units $\mathbb Z_2^\times$. And conversely, any combination of such a $(y_n)_n$ and $(u_n)_n$ gives a $2$-adic sequence going to $0$. But

$$\dfrac{f(x_n)-f(0)}{x_n-0} = \frac{1}{u_n}$$

i.e. for any $2$-adic unit $u$ you want (say, $17$), you can find a sequence going to $0$ such that the differential quotient in question goes to that number. And that's already achievable by looking at the sequence $x_n = \frac{1}{u}2^n$ with constant $u_n := u$.

(This is user coiso' point in a comment where their $a$ is our $u$. Since the limit of the differential quotient of $g$, if it exists for a certain sequence, is $1$ plus that of $f$ divided by $3$, this also retrieves Jyrki's examples of getting $1+1/3$ for the sequence $x_n = 2^n$ i.e. $u=1$ but $1-1/3$ for the sequence $x_n = -2^n$ i.e. $u=-1$.)

For most sequences, this will not even converge.