# Is $f$ differentiable over all $\Bbb Z_2$?

Tags: calculus, p-adic-number-theory

Let $f$ be the restriction of a function on the 2-adic numbers (and with the 2-adic topology), to the conventional integers $\Bbb Z$.

Let $f(x)=(3x+2^{\nu_2(x)})/4$ for positive integers

Let $f(x)=(3x+2^{\nu_2(x)})/2$ for negative integers

Let $f(0)=0$

Then change my mind, but I have that $f$ is differentiable everywhere including zero using:

$f'(x)=\lim_{a\to x}\dfrac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$

Including derivative $f'(0)=1$ at zero.

**Question**

How should $f$ be extended such that it is differentiable over all the periodic 2-adic numbers?  Can the same positive / negative rule be used to define the derivative elsewhere or does it need to be enhanced, or is it even impossible?

**My thoughts**

FWIW if the answer to this falls into the "it can be done but you need to construct the divisor carefully" category, then the following is what I have worked out:  One can **uniquely** factor a periodic 2-adic unit into $2^tu+n$ where $u$ is a periodic 2-adic unit whose binary representation is an infinitely repeating Lyndon word, and $t\in\Bbb Z$ and $n\in\Bbb N:n<2^tu$ the binary representation of $u$.

Then at one extreme, representing the divisor in $f$ when $x$ is a negative integers we have the Lyndon word $\overline1_2\mapsto \frac12$ and at the other extreme representing the divisor in $f$ when $x$ is a positive integer, we have $\overline0_2\mapsto \frac14$.  Maybe by a suitable definition of a bijection from the Lyndon words to power of $2$ divisors we can maintain continuity?  If so, what's the correct function?

Comment: This $f$ is not even $2$-adic continuous. Positive integers and negative integers are both dense in $\Bbb Z_2$.

Comment: Thanks @coiso i was starting to suspect as much.